# Error submitting a hash to sqlite db golang

Tags: sqlite, go, hash, bcrypt

Trying to send a hash from a form to an sqlite database

```
func Signup(r http.ResponseWriter, w *http.Request)  {
    w.ParseForm()
    email := w.Form.Get("Email")
    if !govalidator.IsEmail(email) {
        utils.ServerResponse("email is incorrect", "frontend/index.html", r)
        return
    }

    password := w.Form.Get("Password")
    hash, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte("Password"), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
    if password == "" || len(password) < 6 {
        utils.ServerResponse("Password length must be longer than 6 letters and must contain numbers and uppercase letters", "frontend/index.html", r)
        return
    }

    query := fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO User (email, password)", VALUES "email", "hash")

    fmt.Println(query, string(hash)) // put this here for debugging

    statement , err := db.SqliteDatabase.Prepare(query)
```

Output in the terminal and nothing submits to the database:

```
INSERT INTO User (email, password)
                VALUES ("email" , "hash")
        %!(EXTRA string=test@example.com, string=21818921) $2a$10$S5DObh/Kwbnl1JMvb.Xzf.Vo9SJsOMDaFugWstf/1xGCPTnZBxr3y
near "%": syntax error
```

Comment: You are using Sprintf incorrectly. Read the docs.

Comment: That's correct, fixed it and posted the answer to my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Discovered i was using the fmt.Sprintf function incorrectly and fixed it.

```
query := fmt.Sprintf(`
        INSERT INTO User (email, password)
        VALUES ("%s" , "%s")
    `, email, hash)
```

Comment: I downvote because you should **never** **ever** use fmt sprint to build sql queries. Top one reason hackers blow your systems.

Comment: @mh-cbon i clearly stated it is for debugging, this is on development. I know better.